# Tcl is not giving me the correct hexa number for 11 digit decimal conversion

Tags: tcl

For example:

I have a decimal value with 11 digits lets say .. `14596457848`

When I do this conversion using the calculator I am getting the exact value like `366044578`

If I do it using the below tcl code 3 is missing

```
format %4x 14596457848
```

Ans: `66044578`

Please help me on this soon

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, please click on the tick mark to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

For historical reasons, `format`'s number specifiers default to working with 32-bit integers. Your value is larger than that so you need the `l` (64-bit) or `ll` (bignum) modifiers.

```
format %4lx 14596457848
```

→ `366044578`